# Case When Else In Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query like below, but I got the following error::

> SQL Error [907] [42000]: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Code:

```
SELECT 
    typ.ID ID, typ.DETAILS DETAILS 
FROM 
    LMP_ORDER_MW_HOST_SVC_TYP typ 
LEFT JOIN 
    LMP_ORDER_MW_HOST_TRX lomht ON typ.ID = lomht.ORDER_SVC_TYP_ID 
WHERE 
    typ.ID IN (CASE 
                   WHEN lomht.ORDER_TRX_ID = :ORDER_TRX_ID 
                       THEN ('31', '21', '51', '45', '35') 
                       ELSE ('12', '13') 
               END);
```

Comment: `case` *expression* should be scalar by definition: *An expression is a combination of one or more values, operators, and SQL functions **that evaluates to a value*** Tuple (`(1,2,3)`) is not a value, there's no such datatype in Oracle. You should use boolean logic with different`in` conditions (branches of your `case` expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CASE` expressions are really intended to generate new values.  Instead, you should just use straight and/or logic in your `WHERE` clause:

```sql
SELECT typ.ID ID, typ.DETAILS DETAILS
FROM LMP_ORDER_MW_HOST_SVC_TYP typ
LEFT JOIN LMP_ORDER_MW_HOST_TRX lomht 
    ON typ.ID = lomht.ORDER_SVC_TYP_ID 
WHERE
    lomht.ORDER_TRX_ID = :ORDER_TRX_ID AND
    typ.ID IN ('31', '21', '51', '45', '35') OR
    lomht.ORDER_TRX_ID != :ORDER_TRX_ID AND
    typ.ID ('12', '13');
```

Comment: so i can't use When Case else sir?

Comment: In your exact case, a `CASE` expression always outputs a _single_ value expression, not a collection or list.  You are trying to compare `typ.ID` against a list of values, but `CASE` cannot output this.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, a `CASE` expression returns a single scalar value (not a comparison or a list of values).

Instead of using a `CASE` expression, you can use the `AND` and `OR` logical operators and brackets for precedence and you need to make sure that you check the equivalent `ELSE` condition tests for `NULL` values (because, with trinary logic, `NULL` is never equal nor not-equal to anything else):

```sql
SELECT typ.ID,
       typ.DETAILS
FROM   LMP_ORDER_MW_HOST_SVC_TYP typ 
       LEFT OUTER JOIN LMP_ORDER_MW_HOST_TRX lomht
       ON typ.ID = lomht.ORDER_SVC_TYP_ID 
WHERE  (   lomht.ORDER_TRX_ID = :ORDER_TRX_ID 
       AND typ.ID IN ('31', '21', '51', '45', '35')
       )
OR     (   (  lomht.ORDER_TRX_ID != :ORDER_TRX_ID
           OR lomht.ORDER_TRX_ID IS NULL
           OR :ORDER_TRX_ID      IS NULL
           )
       AND typ.ID IN ('12', '13')
       );
```